# JS, как удалить все нули из строки после точки?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть любое число, как для начала найти все нули с помощью регулярного выражения?
К примеру такое число - `0.001`.

Регулярное выражение: `.[0].*`, но выбирается и единичка.

Comment: Каким должен быть результат? `0.1`?

Answer (score 1):

Ну если я вопрос правильно понял...

```js
var x = 0.001
var s = x + ''
console.log(s.replace(/\.0+/, '.'))
```

Comment: Или так: 0*\.?0*  ;)

Comment: Ну или так: `(?<=(?<=\d)\.)[0]{1,}`

Comment: @LLENN, бррррррррр какой-то...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, просто в вашем выражении точка тоже попадает под выражение.

Comment: @LLENN 1. ну и что? 2. поддержка предпросмотра назад в js весьма сомнительна. 3. Вообще не понимаю, зачем тебе два вложенных предпросмотра.

Comment: @Qwertiy, кстати тоже интересно зачем два вложенных, когда одного предостаточно

Comment: Тоже хотел так написать. +

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующее:

```
(?<=\.)[0]*
```

https://regex101.com/r/xxck6h/3

Comment: 1. Неверно: `100.001`. 2. Зачем пихать предпросмотр назад туда, где он не нужен? Тем более, он ещё мало где поддерживается.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант удаления нулей после точки до первой встречи цифры (кроме нуля)

```js
var string = '0.001';
console.log(string.replace(/(?<=\.)[0]+/, ''));
```

Вариант для удаления абсолютно всех нулей после запятой

```js
var string = '0.001337014880';
console.log(string.replace(/(?!^0)(?<=\.?)[0]+/g, ''));
```

Comment: Зачем пихать предпросмотр назад туда, где он не нужен? Тем более, он ещё мало где поддерживается.